# Spring data geode - how to filter partitions in functions

Tags: spring-data, geode

I created a region(key: [id, date]) with a PartitionResolver based on date, which means the region is bucketed/partitioned by date. now in function implementation, I want to filter certain date partitions so that I don't have to loop over `Map<IdDate, Entity> regionData` to filter data for particular dates. The idea is to filter date partitions by straightaway discarding irrelevant buckets which makes the filtering faster.
I found that there is an option to use `@Filter` annotation in functions, but this seems to expect a set of keys. But I would like to provide a set of partition keys (dates in my use case).

Is this possible in spring geode?

Answer (score 0):

The [`PartitionedRegionHelper.getHashKey()`](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/internal/cache/PartitionedRegionHelper.java#L515) method is internally used to map the `bucketId` to an specific `key` within a partitioned region. When executing a data dependant `Function` on a `PartitionRegion` (`FunctionService.onRegion().withFilter()`), the executor internally retrieves the list of buckets and members using the afore mentioned method.

Considering that `spring-data-geode` ends up using the `withFilter()` method when configuring the function through the `@Filter` annotation, and assuming that the custom implementation for your `PartitionResolver.getRoutingObject()` method returns the `Date` part of the `key`, it should be possible to achieve what you want by just using some dummy data for the `id`. Have you tried it?.

I might be wrong as I haven't tested this myself (will try to write a small scenario), but it should work.

Cheers.